# issue in json data fetching and rendering in nextjs

Tags: json, next.js

I am trying out a small sample in nextjs. All that the proj does is to fetch json data from a file and try displaying it in list of a component. But the behavior is weird. Its getting into infinite loop and I have no clue what's wrong. Could some one take a look at https://github.com/SamplesForMurthy/sampleCode and help me figure out what the issue is? Not able to fetch the data nor I am able to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cloned and fixed. You don't need to use fs.readFileSync here, or fs at all for that matter. You can simply import the `.json` file as an arbitrarily named variable then map it out.
[image: rendered-data]

Here is how I got the data rendering:

```js
import React from 'react';
import testData from '../TestData/SampleData.json';
import SampleParentComponent from '../components/SampleParentComponent';

function TestPage({ filecontent }) {
    console.log(`filecontent: ${filecontent}`);
    return (
        <div>
            <SampleParentComponent data={filecontent}></SampleParentComponent>
        </div>
    );
}

export const getStaticProps = async ctx => {
    console.log(ctx.query);
    const filecontent = await testData;
    return {
        props: { filecontent }
    };
};

export default TestPage;

/**
 * (property) filecontent: {
    data: {
        seqNo: number;
        contactName: string;
    }[];
}
 */
```